# debian clients connected to the same switch, ping problems

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ping

I have two machines that are connected to the same switch. Machines have multiple ethernet interfaces connected to the different networks. Computer A can ping an antenna which is connected to the same switch, but can not ping Computer B using correct interface.(via ping -I eth2 in my case), but Computer B can ping the antenna and can ping Computer A using correct interface ( via ping -I eth9 in my case).

I checked interface details they both have same subnet masks, I tried tracert -i , results were consistent with the problem I mentioned above but it didn't reveal much. tracert on computer A took 30 hops and in the end it couldn't reach computer B. route command showed me routing tables are similar, only difference that I see is computer B have two interfaces defined in subnet but only one is physically connected at the time, can that be causing this weird problem? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

computer A

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:02:e3:5c  
          inet addr:16.1.8.61  Bcast:16.1.63.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe02:e35c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:144031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:11302308 (10.7 MiB)  TX bytes:853551 (833.5 KiB)
          Memory:fe8e0000-fe900000 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:d0:c9:ce:6d:7c  
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2d0:c9ff:fece:6d7c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:17398 (16.9 KiB)  TX bytes:41787 (40.8 KiB)
          Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8480 (8.2 KiB)  TX bytes:8480 (8.2 KiB)
```

computer B

```
    eth7      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:d0:c9:ce:6c:b2  
          inet addr:16.1.8.64  Bcast:16.1.63.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2d0:c9ff:fece:6cb2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:134026 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3212 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10611871 (10.1 MiB)  TX bytes:272509 (266.1 KiB)
          Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000 

eth8      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:02:e1:c2  
          inet addr:192.168.1.60  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:8228  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:fe8e0000-fe900000 

eth9      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:05:ca:02:e1:c3  
          inet addr:192.168.1.57  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a05:caff:fe02:e1c3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:40794 (39.8 KiB)  TX bytes:15778 (15.4 KiB)
          Memory:fe880000-fe8a0000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22872 (22.3 KiB)  TX bytes:22872 (22.3 KiB)
```

Routing Table A

`Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
localnet        *               255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         pfizmir.xxxx 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0`

Comment: Can you show us interface details ?

Comment: I edited the original question to include the interface details, in computer A eth2 is connected to the switch, in computer B eth9 is connected to the switch.

Comment: can You show routing table from host A ?

Comment: If you have two separate physical interfaces on the same network, connected to the same VLAN, you will need to set up a few specific routing rules, ensuring that the server responds on the  same interface that it received the packet on.

Comment: @alan I edited the original question to include the routing table.

Comment: @nick do I need to specify the rule on host A or B?

Comment: A probably doesn't like pinging 192.168.1.57 and getting a response back from 192.168.1.60 (or vice versa). Can you see the pings arrive on host B? I'd place the rules on Host B..

Comment: how do I check if B receives the pings, should I use something like tcpdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two separate physical interfaces on the same network, connected to the same VLAN, you will need to set up a few specific routing rules, ensuring that the server responds on the  same interface that it received the packet on.

With `ip` you can create additional tables, tables that are only used when traffic is received on one of the interfaces.

First you will want to create two separate routing tables.

```
echo 201 E9 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo 200 E8 >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

this creates the tables which will decide how to route the packets.

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0 dev eth9 src 192.168.1.57 table E9
ip route add default via <your gateway for 192.168.1.0> table E9
ip route add 192.168.1.0 dev eth8 src 192.168.1.60 table E8
ip route add default via  <your gateway for 192.168.1.0> table E8

ip rule add from 192.168.1.57 table E9
ip rule add from 192.168.1.60 table E8
```

and that should ensure that the packets that arrive on eth9 are responded to on eth9 and so on.

As always, I recommend reading this [page](http://lartc.org/howto/index.html), it explains the concepts very well, and also gives you many more examples.